# CakePHP Upper Case Table Name MySQL

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have a MYSQL table being produced and populated by another program that I have no control over, The problem is that the table name is all upper-case "AFTER_HOURS", and if i use

```
class ah extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'AFTER_HOUR';
    var $primaryKey = 'ID';
    var $displayField = 'ID';
}?>
```

i get the error:

Error: Database table a_f_t_e_r__h_o_u_rs for model Ah was not found.

Im still new to cake, how can i resolve this??

THANKS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify what table a model should use, do this in your model:

```
var $useTable = 'AFTER_HOUR';
```

Details here: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1059/useTable